Keycloak login or any page says "Page not found"
keycloak login
I tried to deploy keycloak in kubernetes. setup using the given service and deployment yaml given in the guide of keycloak.
env:
          args: ["startdev"]
          env:
            - name: DB_VENDOR
              value: h2
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
              value: "admin"
            - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
              value: "admin"
            - name: KC_PROXY
              value: "edge"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /realms/master
              port: 8080

routing was given through kong route with strip path having /keycloak as its base.
i'm using this image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.4
i tried running this locally in docker and it works normally. but when i tried to deploy in kubernetes all url just gives me page not found.
admin account and realm master was created through env. even with /realms/master it shows page not found.

i already tried changing the route to base "/" only
tried putting a --hostname in args
tried also having a frontend url
tried running in prod

all gave page not found error

What is the URL in the top when page not found shows?
